# Have strange confused in ActiveRecord associations has_one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Have two model `A`,`B` like this:

```
   class A < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :b,:foreign_key => :sid
   end

   class B < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :a,:foreign_key => :sid
   end
```

`A` has field `id` which auto_increment, filed `sid` which uniq

`B` has filed `sid` that i set to primary_key

Now i want get `b` instance through `a` instance. my code like this:

```
A.frist.b
```

i got error

```
SELECT `b_model_name`.* FROM `b_model_name` WHERE `b_model_name`.`sid` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

attention in database model `B` have the record which associations model `A` first by `sid`

i want to know why the query will like

```
 SELECT `b_model_name`.* FROM `b_model_name` WHERE `b_model_name`.`sid` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

why not :

```
 SELECT `b_model_name`.* FROM `b_model_name` WHERE `b_model_name`.`sid` = a.sid LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks okay to me

One of the reasons you've been downvoted is I think you're going against convention by defining a custom `foreign_key` for a standard [`has_one` / `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) relationship

And furthermore, I can't see what you're actually trying to achieve! If the models were completely different, you'd have to define a custom relationship, but it looks like they're a standard `has_one / belongs_to` relationship

Perhaps you could try this:

```
   class A < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :b, class_name: "B"
   end

   class B < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :a, class_name: "A"
   end

   as
   id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | created_at | updated_at

   bs
   id | a_id | b1 | b2 | b3 | created_at | updated_at
```